# Incipient instability in Microsoft Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012-r2, task-scheduler, azure

Context: Microsoft Azure; Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have a small number of Tasks in the Scheduler. All are marked, in the Settings tab, as "If the task is already running, then the follow rule applies: 'Do not start a new instance'".

This is fine for a few days. Then the scheduler appears to start a new instance of each task while one is running. These show up in the Task Manager next to the already running task, but marked as "Suspended."

This seems to be a general sign of system instability. Fairly soon after this behaviour surfaces, SQL Server starts misbehaving.

I'm in the process of writing a maintenance script (which will have to use the scheduler as well, more's the pity) that will count instances of production applications and send the dev team an sms if more than one is in memory (one running, one suspended.) That's the short term workaround. A long term fix would be better.

Has anyone encountered anything like this and, if so, what's the fix?

**Response to Suggestions**

I could put

```
var currProcName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
if (Process.GetProcessesByName(currProcName).Length > 1)
{
    Warn($"An instance of {currProcName} is already running. Only one instance of this application is allowed.");
    return;
}
```

or its equivalent into all EXEs. However, in the current setup, this would never 
issue a warning because the second instance of the EXE does not run as such but appears in the Task Manager as "Suspended".

Allowing the Scheduler to start a job whether it's already running or not and requiring the EXE itself deto termine whether it should run or not seems somewhat inefficient as it then requires each EXE to launch and possibly die every minute rather than allow the Scheduler to determine whether a launch is required or not.

At have about 20 tasks being scheduled, some every minute, some every 5, some every 60.

**Responses to Questions asked in Comments #1**

Q: What are you running exactly with the Task Scheduler like a batch script, an exe file, PowerShell script, or what?

A: EXEs only, e.g.

```
<Actions Context="Author">
  <Exec>
    <Command>Handler.exe</Command>
    <WorkingDirectory>C:\Web\Project</WorkingDirectory>
  </Exec>
</Actions>
```

Q: How do you have the task setup in the scheduler options wise?

A: Sample Settings from XML file:

```
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
```

Sample Triggers from XML file

```
<Triggers>
  <CalendarTrigger>
    <Repetition>
      <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
      <Duration>P1D</Duration>
      <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
    </Repetition>
    <StartBoundary>2016-03-09T14:20:00</StartBoundary>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT30M</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <ScheduleByDay>
      <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
    </ScheduleByDay>
  </CalendarTrigger>
</Triggers>
```

**Responses to Questions asked in Comments #2**

Q: Did you disable and then enable these tasks?

A: The tasks are regularly disabled and re-enabled when updates are applied.

Q: Were the tasks imported from an XML file?

A: The original task (on another server) was created using the GUI. The result was exported to XML, moved to the current server, edited and imported.

Q: If you recreate the task, does this fix the problem?

A: No.

Q: Does the task terminate with an exit code?

A: If you mean "does the task terminate with an Environment.Exit(n)?" then yes. However, the value is not checked as the task is defined as an EXE rather than as part of a larger CMD.

Q: Is it possible that the scheduled task terminated exactly when the new task is supposed to start?

A: How would I establish that?

Q: Can two instances of the same task running concurrently explain the instability you are seeing?

A: I'm not sure I understand the question. At no point do we permit two instances to run concurrently. The current situation is that at a time of its own choosing, Windows permits one instance to run and allows another to run but in "suspended" mode. Interestingly, our current experience is that a suspended task can't be terminated. Only a running task can be terminated.

Comment: It's probably because you're a bugmagnet ;)

Comment: What are you running exactly with the Task Scheduler like a batch script, an exe file, PowerShell script, or what? How do you have the task setup in the scheduler options wise? Knowing all of this can make a difference too. I assume you are running an executable file or something and the name of this process you see in memory there is what indicates more than one is running. I think you should include detail of the scheduled task setup and what you are running with it, and maybe screen shots of what you see that indicate the issue, etc.

Comment: @Bob very likely. Very very likely.

Comment: @ITSnuggles yes, good point. I shall add as soon as I get a larger slab of time.

Comment: What do you see that indicates SQL Server is misbehaving too? Is this an app that makes connections to the SQL Server DBs?

Comment: @ITSnuggles yes it is all part of a large SaaS package we run for our clients.

Comment: I would submit this as a comment but I don't have the reputation, so I hope you see it before it's deleted (mods really don't like non-answers). I suggest enable tasks history then review the history for that task. That should help you diagnose the issue. Also, this reminds me of a similar issue I had but in Windows Server 2008. I posted to technet but did not receive a satisfactory answer: [Scheduled task runs twice, bug in task scheduler](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0eea44e5-440d-493c-91df-9eee42e72c7d)

Comment: Questions: (1) Did you disable and then enable these tasks? (2) Were the tasks imported from an XML file? (3) If you recreate the task, does this fix the problem? (4) Does the task terminate with an exit code? (5) Is it possible that the scheduled task terminated exactly when the new task is supposed to start? (6) Can two instances of the same task running concurrently explain the instability you are seeing?

Comment: @harrymc Answers given to your questions

Comment: @ITSnuggles Answers given to your questions

Comment: @ITSnuggles response to suggestion in body of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Task Scheduler and Idle Conditions

There seems to be two ways of configuring a **Task Scheduler** job regarding the **Idle Conditions**.

1. If the `StopOnIdleEnd` is set to **true**, then the `RestartOnIdle` should be **true** as well if the desired result is to **terminate and restart a task**.

   > ### [Cycling Idle Condition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx)
   >
   > If the computer is cycling in and out of the idle state, you can
   >   terminate and restart the task using the following idle conditions.
   >
   > To terminate and restart a task, ***both properties and elements must be set to True***:
   >
   > - To terminate the task when the idle condition ends, set the [StopOnIdleEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380722(v=vs.85).aspx) property or the [StopOnIdleEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380722(v=vs.85).aspx) element to True.
   > - To restart the task when the computer cycles into the idle condition
   >     again, set the [RestartOnIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380721(v=vs.85).aspx) property or the [RestartOnIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380721(v=vs.85).aspx) element to
   >     True.
   >
   > ---
   >
   > **Example Config**
   >
   > ```
   > <IdleSettings>
   >   <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
   >   <RestartOnIdle>true</RestartOnIdle>
   > </IdleSettings>
   > ```

   Both of these should be set to **True**.

---

2. If the desired result is to **not have the task stop running in an idle condition**, then you will want to ensure both the [RestartOnIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380721(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [StopOnIdleEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380722(v=vs.85).aspx) are set to **false**.

   > **Example Config**
   >
   > ```
   > <IdleSettings>
   >   <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
   >   <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
   > </IdleSettings>
   > ```

Both of these should be set to **False**.

Comment: @bugmagnet .... I just thought of something else too. Perhaps you do not want the process to stop running on idle condition and thus having both set to false would suffice for your need. I will append this to my answer once I hear back from you, etc. I would think if you want Task Scheduler to stop if on idle condition then you probably want it to restart it too and thus having the RestartOnIdle set to false may be why the suspended processes stay out there and perhaps Task Scheduler cannot see suspended process for the `Do not start a new instance` and thus you also need to allow the restart.

Comment: If the `RestartOnIdle` does it's job, then I would think the `Do not start a new instance` should do it's job too and suspended processes would go away perhaps.

Comment: I think that for our purposes that we should never "consider the system as being idle, regardless of [lack of] user activity or [lack of] resource consumption"

Comment: @bugmagnet Great, I've added to my answer as I said I would once I heard back. I appreciate you following my advice and disclosing the configs and it appearing to help find the cause potentially and hopefully a solution too. I look forward to hearing back from you regarding the matter and wish you great success!! Respectfully~

Comment: Okay, will go with your suggestion. It'll take a few days to see if the changes work or not. I've just been through all 25 scheduled tasks on our first azure server. There'll be a few less on the second one. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

My take on your problem is that it's caused by the line :

```
<StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
```

Here is what I theorize is your scenario :

- The process stops in a state of wait in a kernel call.
  In this state it cannot be stopped.
- The computer entered the idle state and then went out of it.
- The Task Scheduler tried to stop the process, but only managed to suspend it in the zombie state (stopped but cannot terminate).
- The task being marked terminated, the Task Scheduler started a new one.
- As the original task was perhaps in the middle of an SQL transaction
  and may still hold locks, the behavior of the SQL database was impaired.

The solution should be to set `StopOnIdleEnd` to `false`.
There is no reason to terminate the task because the computer entered
the idle state, however briefly.
In fact, it's a very bad idea to brutally stop any task which is
connected to an SQL server, because it leaves the ongoing transaction
uncompleted and not even rolled-back.